# pattern finding in python and report as a tab separated text file

Tags: python

I have a big text file like this small example:

small example:

```
>chr9:128683-128744
GGATTTCTTCTTAGTTTGGATCCATTGCTGGTGAGCTAGTGGGATTTTTTGGGGGGTGTTA
>chr16:134222-134283
AGCTGGAAGCAGCGTGGGAATCACAGAATGGCCGAGAACTTAAAGGCTTTGCTTGGCCTGG
>chr16:134226-134287
GGAAGCAGCGTGGGAATCACAGAATGGACGGCCGATTAAAGGCTTTGCTTGGCCTGGATTT
>chr1:134723-134784
AAGTGATTCACCCTGCCTTTCCGACCTTCCCCAGAACAGAACACGTTGATCGTGGGCGATA
>chr16:135770-135831
GCCTGAGCAAAGGGCCTGCCCAGACAAGATTTTTTAATTGTTTAAAAACCGAATAAATGTT
>chr16:135787-135848
GCCCAGACAAGATTTTTTAATTGTTTAAAAACCGAATAAATGTTTTATTTCTAGAAAACTG
>chr16:135788-135849
CCCAGACAAGATTTTTTAATTGTTTAAAAACCGAATAAATGTTTTATTTCTAGAAAACTGT
>chr16:136245-136306
CACTTCACAAATAGAAGGCTGTCAGAGAGACAGGGACAGGCCACACAAGTGTTTCTGCACA
>chr7:146692-146753
GTGTGACCAAAACTTAGGATGTTAGCCGAACTCTCCGTTACTATCATTTTGGATTTCCAGT
>chr8:147932-147993
GGTAAAGGTAAATACATAAACAAACATAAAACCGATCCTATTGTAATTTTGGTTTGTAACT
```

this file is divided into different groups and every group has 2 parts (2 lines). the 1st line which starts with `>` is ID and the 2nd line is a sequence of characters. length of every sequence of characters is 61.
I have a short sequence (which is `CCGA`) I would like to scan every 2nd part for this short sequence. and output would be a text file with 2 columns.

1st column: is the position where the beginning of short sequence is located (every 2nd part has 61 characters so in the output I will report the position of characters which is a number). 
2nd column: is the count of number of times that the beginning of short sequence is located at that specific position.

for instance for the following sequence of characters the beginning of short sequence is at position `49`.

```
GCCTGAGCAAAGGGCCTGCCCAGACAAGATTTTTTAATTGTTTAAAAACCGAATAAATGTT
```

for the small example, the expected output would look like this:

expected output:

```
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  0
13  0
14  0
15  0
16  0
17  0
18  0
19  0
20  0
21  1
22  0
23  0
24  0
25  0
26  1
27  0
28  0
29  0
30  0
31  1
32  4
33  0
34  0
35  0
36  0
37  0
38  0
39  0
40  0
41  0
42  0
43  0
44  0
45  0
46  0
47  0
48  0
49  1
50  0
51  0
52  0
53  0
54  0
55  0
56  0
57  0
58  0
59  0
60  0
61  0
```

I am trying to do that in python using the following code. but the output is not like what I want.

```
infile = open('infile.txt', 'r')
ss = 'CCGA'
count = 0
for line in infile:
    if not line.startswith('>'):
        for match in pattern.finder(ss):
            count +=1
            POSITION = pattern.finder(ss)
            COUNT = count
```

do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, in your code: `line.startswith('<')`; did you mean `line.startswith('>')` here?

Comment: Can the `CCGA` sequence appear more than once in a single line?

Comment: @Patrick Haugh yes that is possible

Comment: Can we see your `pattern.finder`? Why are you calling it twice, and why does it seem to yield an iterable the first time and a position integer the second time, and how is it fed the actual line it's supposed to test?

Answer (score 2):

The below uses [`finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) to find all non-overlapping occurences of the `CCGA` pattern, and creates a mapping from the index of the beginning of the sequence to the number of times a sequence has begun at that index.

```
from re import compile
from collections import defaultdict

pat = compile(r'CCGA')
mapping = defaultdict(int)

with open('infile.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.startswith('>'):
            for match in pat.finditer(line):
                mapping[match.start() + 1] += 1

for i in range(1, 62):
    print("{:>2} {:>2}".format(i, mapping[i]))
```

prints

```
 1  0
 2  0
 3  0
 4  0
 5  0
 6  0
 7  0
 8  0
 9  0
10  0
11  0
12  0
13  0
14  0
15  0
16  0
17  0
18  0
19  0
20  0
21  1
22  0
23  0
24  0
25  0
26  1
27  0
28  0
29  0
30  0
31  1
32  4
33  0
34  0
35  0
36  0
37  0
38  0
39  0
40  0
41  0
42  0
43  0
44  0
45  0
46  0
47  0
48  0
49  1
50  0
51  0
52  0
53  0
54  0
55  0
56  0
57  0
58  0
59  0
60  0
61  0
```

One way to export it to a file would be to use the `print` function

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w+') as outfile:
    for i in range(1, 62):
        print(i, mapping[i], sep='\t', file=outfile)
```

Comment: i think it works. how can I export it into a tab separated file?